# Manufacturing problem, exponential distribution

Tags: probability

> A manufacturing process produces $92%$ good chips (G) and $8%$ bad chips (B).
>   The lifetime, in seconds, of chips is exponentially distributed
>   $E(\lambda)$.For good chips, $\lambda_1=\frac{1}{20000}$. For bad chips, $\lambda_2=\frac{1}{1000}$. Every chip is tested for $50 seconds$ prior to leaving the factory. The only chips that pass the test will be sent out to customers .
>
> a. Find the probability that a good chip will be sent out to customers.
>   Find the probability that a bad chip will be sent out to customers.
>
> b. Evaluate the percentage of good chips among a great lot of chips that will be sent out to customers.

I used this equation to solve :

$P(X>50)=1−P(X\le50)=1−(1−)$

So $P1(X>50)=0.9975$

$P2(X>50)= 0.9512$

Am I right? Question b I don't know how to solve.

Comment: There's a typo, $P(X\le50)=1−(1−)$ - it looks incomplete.

Comment: For (b), let $B$ be the event chip passes, and $A$ the event it is good. We want the conditional probability $\Pr(A|B)$. This is $\Pr(A\cap B)/\Pr(B)$. Compute these two probabilities. Remark: Seems like a poor testing process.

Comment: @JessePFrancis my mistake it is Exp(-t/20000)

Comment: @CuongBui, You can correct it yourself! 'e^{\frac{-t}{20000}}' between '$' symbols! For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773) and 
[here](/help/notation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My defined events are:

S: A chip is sent out

G: A randomly picked chip is a good one

$B=\overline{G}$: A randomly picked chip is a bad one

You have calculated $P(S | G)=0.9975$ and $P(S | B)=0.9512$.

You are asked to calculate $\frac{P(S \cap G)}{P(S)}$

$P(S \cap G)=P(S|G)\cdot P(G)$ and $P(S \cap B)=P(S \cap \overline G)=P(S|B)\cdot P(B)$

$P(S)=P((S \cap G) \cup (S \cap B))=P((S \cap G) \cup (S \cap \overline G))=P(S \cap G)+P(S \cap \overline G)$.

The values of P(B) and P(G) are given.

Comment: Can you tell me more detail  why P(S/G) = 0.9975, Exponential distribution confused me a lot. And why in part b you know calculate P(G/S) I think it is similar to part a_1. Help me!!! that is confused me

Comment: The notation and formula for the conditional probability depends not on the distribution. $P(S|G)$ is the probability, that at a chip is sent out, given that the chip is a good one. This is similar to the formulation in the exercise. P(G|S) is the probability, that a chip is a good one, given that the chip is sent out. If a chip is sent it can be good or bad. Thus you have all the chips wich are sent out. This is expressed by $P(S)$. The qood one chips,, which are sent out is expressed by  $P(S \cap G)$. Sure the formulas are expressed in terms of probability. (Will be continued Too many char)

Answer (score 0):

Let $$G_n\stackrel{i.i.d.}{\sim}\mathrm{Exp}\left(\frac1{20000}\right)$$ for $n=1,2,\ldots,92$ and $$B_n\stackrel{i.i.d.}{\sim}\mathrm{Exp}\left(\frac1{1000}\right)$$ for $n=1,2,\ldots,8$. Then
$$\mathbb P(G_n>50) = e^{-50\cdot\frac1{20000}}=e^{-\frac1{400}}\approx 0.9975$$
and
$$\mathbb P(B_n>50) = e^{-50\cdot\frac1{1000}}=e^{-\frac1{20}}\approx 0.9512.$$
The expected fraction of good chips among a great lot of chips is just the fraction of good chips to bad chips, weighted by the probability of being sent out:

$$\frac{92 e^{-\frac1{400}}} {92e^{-\frac1{400}} + 8e^{-\frac1{20}}}\approx 0.9234 $$